# Dynamically resizing UICollectionView using AutoLayout

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, autolayout

I have two collection views that I would like to dynamically resize based on the size of their superview. The layout resembles this:

[image: Collection views]

Now, I want to allow the user to resize the superview (grey) by using a UIPanGesture, which works fine, but at the same time I would like the collection views to resize automatically (i.e. the collection view is stuck to the bottom of the screen and the height grows larger). I've tried adding constraints between the collection views and the superview for equal height, but that does not dynamically resize the collection views.

Comment: Have you tried the constraint **Pin - Top Space to Superview**? This constraint should make sure that the top of the view you apply this to will always stick to the superviews top to a certain distance. There's also a good tutorial on Autolayout on [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2)